# Combination of quantum numbers for a particle in a 3D box

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, energy, hilbert-space, eigenvalue

For a second excited state, the three combination of quantum number corresponds to 
$$n_{1}=2,n_{2}=2,n_{3}=1$$
or
$$n_{1}=2,n_{2}=1,n_{3}=2$$
or
$$n_{1}=1,n_{2}=2,n_{3}=2.$$

This is from the text Modern physics by Serway. I didn't thought the explanation here was good.

Why are the combination set in this manner? What's the rules?

Comment: You are right, this doesn't seem to make much sense (at least for a cube shaped box). Could you give a more complete quotation from the book, please? Naively I would expect (2,1,1), (1,2,1) and (1,1,2). Is the degeneration of states broken by the particular dimensions of the box in this example?

Comment: Example given by the book:

Determine the wave functions and energy for the second excited level of a particle in a cubic box of edge L. 
What is the degeneracy of this level?

Solution:

The second excited level corresponds to the three combination of quantum numbers 
$$n_{1}=2,n_{2}=2,n_{3}=1$$
or
$$n_{1}=2,n_{2}=1,n_{3}=2$$
or
$$n_{1}=1,n_{2}=2,n_{3}=2$$
@CuriousOne

How does this combination comes about? I haven't quite understood the general rules for determining the combinations.

Comment: OK, now the numbers have changed from your initial post. In a cubic box the states are degenerate (i.e. multiple states have the same energy). The ground state is unique (1,1,1), the next higher states would be (2,1,1), (1,2,1) and (1,1,2), all of which would have the same energy and the energy would be proportional to ${n_1}^2+{n_2}^2+{n_3}^2$, assuming that the book means $n_1=n_x,n_2=n_y,n_3=n_z$. Is that correct?

Comment: @CuriousOne
I apologise for the typos.

Alright, so the ground state is unique. Serway mentioned that the square sums of the 'n' in the first excited state sums to 6. Why 6?

And the triple ordered that you have mentioned, how did those numbers came about?

yes; to your last question.

Comment: The ground state obviously sums to 3. The first excited state sums to 6: 2*2+1*1+1*1 = 4+1+1=6.

Comment: @CuriousOne 
So we have the form 
$$n_{x}^{2}+n_{y}^{2}+n_{z}^{2}=n^{2}$$
But this doesn't tells me where the integers in the triple ordered comes from.

Answer (score 1):

For a particle in a cubic box, the energy levels are given by

$$ E = \dfrac{\hbar^2 \pi^2}{2mL^2} (n_x^2 + n_y^2 + n_z^2) $$

where $n_x, n_y$ and $ n_z $go from $1$ to $\infty$

as you can see from the energy levels that the state with the lowest energy, i.e the ground state should have $n_x = 1, n_y =1$ and $n_z =1$. The first excited state will have the quantum numbers (1,1,2) where due to degeneracy the 2 can appear in any of the three quantum numbers.

The second excited state will have the quantum numbers (1,2,2) where again 1 can appear in any of the three quantum numbers. The rule is only that you have to write down the energy states in increasing order of energy and then identify the least one with the ground state and the ones above with excited states. It would be helpful if you do the example of a box with three sides of different lengths.